# Robot Framework installation issue

Tags: python, robotframework

Whenever i try to install Robot Framework. I am getting the error message below.

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

What is the issue?

I am installing robotframework-2.6.3.win32 with python2.7.2

Comment: Why are you trying to use a 2.6 library with Python 2.7? Have you tried installing robotframework-2.7.6.win32?

Comment: Please comment as to whether your issue has been resolved

Comment: @Junuxx: the 2.6 version doesn't relate to the version of python, it's just the version of the library. It just so happens that the version numbers are similar to python version numbers, but there is no correlation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is causing your specific issue, but I find that using pip or easy_install works for installing robotframework and any plugins on windows

Answer (score 0):

Do you change your installed Python folder name ? Please use internal set-up command line in Python for adding plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from the win32 extension that this is for Windows. In which case I would suggest checking installing with pip which can be found in section 1.3.3
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if pip is installed with your python version

```
pip --version
```

Else use below link to install

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

once pip is installed , you can try to install robotframework with specific version like below

```
pip install MySQL_python==1.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the cause for your issue. but you are trying to install an older version of Robot framework on an Older python build. I suggest you to try a newer version such as 'Robot Framework 3.2.2 (Python 3.7.9 on win32)'. Then, it's easy since pip is installed by default if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4. (you can check by > "py -m pip --version")
Installing Robot Framework is just a two-step process now.

1. install python from https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. install robotframework from https://pypi.org/project/robotframework/ > "pip install robotframework" (You can check the version by > "robot --version")

Read more - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#installation-instructions